# Swap background-color of a specific div with switch/case

Tags: javascript, css, switch-statement, background-color

I'm trying to swap the background-color of some specific divs basing on their content.
Their background-color should swap when their input is like "Lifestyle" or "Politics" or "Economy" or "Local" or "Sports" or "News".

```
var colorInput = document.getElementById('views-field-field-section').textContent;

      switch (colorInput) {
    case 'Lifestyle':
      document.getElementById('views-field-field-section').style.backgroundColor = '#9518b8';                
        break;
    case 'Local':
      document.getElementById('views-field-field-section').style.backgroundColor = '#009fe3';
        break;
    case 'Sports':
      document.getElementById('views-field-field-section').style.backgroundColor = '#95c11f';
        break;
    case 'Economy':
      document.getElementById('views-field-field-section').style.backgroundColor = '#d40d10';
        break;
     case: 'Politics':
       document.getElementById('views-field-field-section').style.backgroundColor = '#ffcc00';
        break;
    default:

        break;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gFN6r/501/

Comment: You should not use same id on multiple elements, it is not valid. Use different id's.

Comment: As I can see on your jsfiddle you have spaces in your html code in div elements, so just `trim` your `colorInput`.

Comment: id has to be unique.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? Or mootools is necessity?

Comment: The unique ID is my problem. It has to be the same ID. Otherwise I could swap the color by CSS only.

Comment: Well using the same id is invalid markup, if you need to retain that id information, using data-id attribute would be an option.

Comment: How can id be the same, when we say that id is unique property?

Comment: We can))))) I will show you in 2 minuties))

Comment: I think it's not a very good solution, but http://stackoverflow.com/a/30643973/4960641

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use ids more than once in an html document. This would be invalid html. I have changed the id to a class, and then used the following code and it works:

```
var colorInput = document.getElementsByClassName('views-field-field-section');
for(i=0; i<colorInput.length; i++) {
      var colorInputText = colorInput[i].textContent.trim();
      switch (colorInputText) {
        case 'Lifestyle':
                colorInput[i].style.backgroundColor = '#9518b8';                
                break;
        case 'Local':
                colorInput[i].style.backgroundColor = '#009fe3';
                break;
        case 'Sports':
                colorInput[i].style.backgroundColor = '#95c11f';
                break;
        case 'Economy':
                colorInput[i].style.backgroundColor = '#d40d10';
                break;
        case 'Politics':
                colorInput[i].style.backgroundColor = '#ffcc00';
                break;
        default:
                text ='Nix!'; 
  }
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gFN6r/505/

Answer (score 4):

Oh man. Don't use the same `id` :) But if it is necessary, ok...

I adjusted a little bit your source code, e.g. there was some syntax error, and added jQuery, hope it's not a problem :)

1. If you use the same `id`, this will not work - `$('#myid')`, but this will - `$('[id=myid]')`
2. Don't forget to use `trim`-like function to remove trailing spaces.
3. And please think a little about how to avoid the same `id` in your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/gFN6r/506/

```
$('[id=views-field-field-section]').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = $.trim(text);

    switch (text) {
        case 'Lifestyle':
            $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#9518b8'});
            break;
        case 'Local':
            $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#009fe3'});
            break;
        case 'Sports':
            $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#95c11f'});
            break;
        case 'Economy':
            $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#d40d10'});
            break;
         case 'Politics':
             $(this).css({backgroundColor: '#ffcc00'});
            break;
        default:
            $(this).text('Nix!');
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it using jQuery to simplify [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6DeHXV8tzdZ2JUJIDFX1?p=preview).
The id is set on the containing parent, while you need to iterate over the children and to check for their content. Note that I've used `.trim()` to eliminate start and trailing spaces so the match case would catch.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate use abs 1 -1 =0 -1 = -1(abs) gets you back to 1 so if you start with $case=1 and just -1 as an absolute value you will tick tock between 1 & 0 either way you always subtract 1